# JSON in This Format in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm working on a project that needs to add JSON to the file after every form submission.
My goal is to get the JSON to look like:

```
{
  "word0":[
    "cheese",
    "burger"
  ],

  "word1":[
    "sup",
    "boi"
  ],

  "word2":[
    "nothin'",
    "much"
  ]
}
```

But I'm not able to add to the JSON file afterwards.

EDIT: I'm thinking about just creating a new file for every form submission.  Would this be a better option?
(Storage size isn't a problem)

Here's my current code that places JSON into a file:

```
$response['word' . $count] = array('word1' => $_POST['firstrow'], 'word2' => $_POST['secondrow']); 
file_put_contents("query.json", file_get_contents("query.json") . json_encode($response) . "\n");
```

Comment: Show us your attempts to accomplish this and we will help you fix them.

Comment: $response['word' . $count] = array('word1' => $_POST['firstrow'], 'word2' => $_POST['secondrow']);

   file_put_contents("query.json", file_get_contents("query.json") . json_encode($response) . "\n");
Here's my current code that places JSON into a file.

Comment: @User I've edited question to include the code in your comment. Please refrain from posting code snippets in the comment section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you have no problem with storage size you can do a new file for every form submission.

But you can make it one large file via reading the writing the file.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("data.json"), true);
$data["word3"] = array("i don't" , "know");
file_put_contents("data.json", json_encode($data));
```

If you want to save on your IO, you can do writing at a specific position via `fseek`.

```
$file = fopen("data.json", "c");
fseek($file, -5, SEEK_END); // 5 character back from the end of the file.
fwrite($file, $newJsonArrayElement);
fclose($file);
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

this is an example snipper, you will need to calculate the characters to seek back from the end and somehow generate the new json.

Comment: You're use of `json_decode` is incorrect. To be able to access the data as an associative array like `$data['word3']` you need to pass a value of `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode`. By default [`json_decode()`](http://us3.php.net//manual/en/function.json-decode.php) serializes into the `stdClass` object.